# Scrolling section by section - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a landing page with 5 sections, each section takes 100vh (always full screen). I would like to implement section change on scroll but couldn't find any example. I do not want to scroll , just on scroll down to show next section and on scroll up to show previous section.

Anyone has some advice on how to do it or a library I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to implement lazy loading or you just want to replace the whole section with another on scroll ?

Comment: @YousafHassan just to replace whole section

Comment: You can take help from https://www.yourwebtech.info/tutorial/how-to-detect-vertical-scroll-direction-using-javascript/   If scroll is upwards, keep displaying previous sections, next otherwise. You may also want to ignore a few scrolls to achieve what you are imagining.